# Getting error as ccenv:latest removal from docker hub caused problem for chaincode instantiation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to init the chaincode on hyperledger fabric 1.4.5 setup with k8s, however getting error as

```
"Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Failed to pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest: API error (404): manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
"
```

Please anybody help me on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`latest` tag has been deprecated. You can add

`CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:your_version`

under peer's environment in compose file.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in Fabric v1.4.8 as it will now look for `fabric-ccenv:1.4` by default, instead of `fabric-ccenv:latest`.

See the [v1.4.8 release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.4.8) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The tag was removed. The workaround is to pull the matching version and tag it locally as latest.

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4.0
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4.0 hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest
```